# cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' on importing requests

Tags: python, collections, python-requests

Python Version: `Python 3.10.4` 
PIP Version: `pip 22.0.4`

So I was trying to make a small project with sockets, I added a feature to upload files but whenever I import requests, it throws this error. Below is the code I ran.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\WireUS\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .connection import is_connection_dropped
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .wait import wait_for_read
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\wait.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .selectors import (
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 14, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple, Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Even this basic code gives me that error.

```py
import requests
import time

r = request.get("google.com").text
print(r)

time.sleep(999)
```

Comment: Looks like the version of requests you are using is out of date. The [Mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) type was moved to `collections.abc`.

Comment: I tried updating but it doesn't work what command do I use to update the module properly?

Comment: It's the `urllib3` version, not the `requests` version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [user2357112-supports-monica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71632325/cannot-import-name-mapping-from-collections-on-importing-requests#comment126598930_71632325) said, running `pip install urllib3` fixes it.

Comment: For me updating Jinja2 with  `pip install -U Jinja2` worked like charming !

Answer (score 5):

Just try to edit the `selectors.py` file

from

```
from collections import Mapping
```

to

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```

This is a compatibility issue between different versions of python 3

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention the schema (http, ftp,https) of your url :

```
import requests
import time

r = requests.get("https://google.com").text
print(r)
```

Comment: It throws the same error if I put only `import requests` in a file and run it.

Comment: @JUB0T ok then the issue is with your installation