# How to fix this long error when trying to install Python modules using pip?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Pip is recognized, but when I try to install a module (for example customtkinter), this error appears.

On a Windows 10 PC with 64 bit and Python 3.10

`pip install customtkinter`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\build_env.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import CommandError, ExternallyManagedEnvironment
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.models import Request, Response
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 149, in <module>
    from . import packages, utils
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._collections import HTTPHeaderDict
  File "c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\_collections.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (c:\users\(Username)\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' on importing requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71632325/cannot-import-name-mapping-from-collections-on-importing-requests)

Comment: try using `pip3 install install customtkinter`